# Play a video when a notification appears while screen is locked

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to play a video while the phone is locked with notification as a trigger?
The video should start playing when the notification arrives.
I don't care if it is an activity or a fragment.

Please reply even if the question is next level stupidity.

Comment: Only with AlarmManager you can play sounds while screen is locked.

Comment: Can the AlarmManager be triggered when a user clicks a push notification? The objective in question has the following flow: 1. User1 receives a push notification (When the phone is locked) informing that another user (User2) has sent a video for User1's viewing` 2. User1 clicks on the push notification (Again, when the phone is locked, the notification expands and the video begins playing while the phone is still locked.` To provide a similar use case, for a deeper understanding of the question, the functionality being sought after is exactly the same as the GIF you can see in the following li

Comment: when you get data notifications via fcm, onMessageReceived gets triggered then you can set an alarm at some seconds after the notification received  for playing some sound.

Comment: And the app you are referring to is showing video after notification click, which is as simple as opening an video activity in Android  by attaching pending intent to notification

Answer (score 0):

The problem was firebase doesnt let you send data notifications.
With AWS it worked like a charm.

Comment: Can you share the code with which you were able to play the video with the screen locked?